# Python + Selenium ActionChain drag_and_drop does not work on Chorme + MacOS

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I've been trying to use selenium to pass around the slider block verification on a website (not a hack its my website no worries)

but somehow the `drag_and_drop` function cannot pick up the block I selected.

The HTML of the block:

`<div class="h-slider-block" style="margin-left: 0px;"></div>`

and when the block is dragged to the right-most position it would be:

`<div class="h-slider-block" style="margin-left: 394px;"></div>`

and the code I used to drag it:

```
knob = browser.find_element_by_class_name('h-slider-block')
# ActionChains(browser).drag_and_drop_by_offset(knob, offset, 0).perform()
ActionChains(browser).click_and_hold(knob).move_by_offset(offset, 0).pause(0.5).release().perform()
```

`offset` is set to `394`.

the code runs fine but as I observe the browser there is no action taken. I tried both combinations above but none of them works. Any Idea?

Update:

Chrome Browser Version: 72.0.3626.121 (Official Build) (64-bit)

ChromeDriver Version: 2.46

macOS Mojave 10.14.3

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious why you are using `driver` here

```
knob = driver.find_element_by_class_name('h-slider-block')
```

and `browser` here.

```
ActionChains(browser).click_and_hold(knob).move_by_offset(offset, 0).pause(0.5).release().perform()
```

I don't know how your `browser` and/or `driver` are defined but does it make any difference if you simply replace `browser` with `driver` in your ActionChains?

```
ActionChains(driver).click_and_hold(knob).move_by_offset(offset, 0).pause(0.5).release().perform()
```

Comment: oh crap it was a typo. `driver` should be `browser` and no it does not work

Comment: You mean there are still no errors and no action is taken?

Comment: I hate ActionChains they never do what they are supposed to. As far as I can see your code should work. Sorry I can’t be more help,  I might revisit this tomorrow